# Does Header use JSON format?

Tags: python-2.7

I know that JSON must use double quotes and will not work with single quotes. But why header can use single quotes like this?

```
 {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
```

Does header use JSON format ?

Answer (score 2):

That's just a `dict` literal which some Python library uses to construct the actual HTTP header, which is simply a sequence of strings, one part of which is strings that look like

```
Content-Type: text/xml
```

in the message actually sent to the HTTP server.